# How is PowerShell Direct different from WinRM or PowerShell Remoting

Tags: windows, powershell, hyper-v, powershell-remoting

Is [PowerShell Direct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct) somehow internally different from [PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands)? Or is it just some additional Hyper-V-specific UI that is based on PowerShell Remoting?

I use PowerShell Direct to manage my Hyper-V VMs. It is convenient for deployment automation because I do not need to enable any special firewall rules or adjust permissions on the VMs - it just works. However, I could also use PowerShell Remoting via WSMan / WinRM that can be used on non Hyper-V machines. This - on the other hand - would require setting up some prerequisites.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sup>Note: The following was gleaned from the documentation and cursory looks at the source code; it is in part conjecture, but I'm hoping it's correct at least in the abstract - do let us know if you have more information.</sup>

- In terms of *features and UX*, **[PowerShell Direct](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct)** - used for **running PowerShell commands in Hyper-V guests (VMs / Windows containers) from the host machine** - is virtually identical to [PowerShell Remoting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_remote_requirements), except that PowerShell Direct features have ***distinct parameters* whose names start with `-VM`, such as `-VMName` vs. `-ComputerName`**.
- That distinct parameters are needed points to at least *partially* distinct technical underpinnings:

  - **While the fundamental parts of the remoting infrastructure - notably the XML-based serialization - are likely shared, PowerShell Direct does *not* use WinRM (WS-MAN) as a transport**, the way PowerShell Remoting does.
  - Instead, **it seems that PowerShell Direct uses [*named pipes*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/ipc/named-pipes) for the communication between the host and the guest machine**; see the following source-code links:

    - [`RemoteSessionNamedPipe.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/6d1d62f2f83b526997d23e0606be9d5708246e9f/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/common/RemoteSessionNamedPipe.cs#L898)
    - [`RemoteSessionHyperVSocket.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/master/src/System.Management.Automation/engine/remoting/common/RemoteSessionHyperVSocket.cs)
    - [`ConsoleHost.cs`](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/blob/6d1d62f2f83b526997d23e0606be9d5708246e9f/src/Microsoft.PowerShell.ConsoleHost/host/msh/ConsoleHost.cs#L207)

**Pros and Cons**:

- PowerShell Direct has the advantage of *not* requiring that the target VM (the guest) be set up for remoting via `Enable-Remoting` first - see [the requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/virtualization/hyper-v-on-windows/user-guide/powershell-direct#requirements).
- Conversely, however, PowerShell Direct is limited to *local* communication between the guest (a Hyper-V VM or container) and its host.

  - If you do need to run PowerShell commands in your VMs from other machines on the network, setting up PowerShell remoting is a must.
- *Presumably*, when running on the VM's host machine, PowerShell Direct performs better than PowerShell Remoting, though that may not matter in practice.